# Task.ContinueWith does not call 2nd task (only first one is running)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

My application lets the user create "Task" objects from the UI and set their order of executions. From there, when the user click "run" all of the Tasks (by order) are sent to a class that suppose to chain and run them. The class is as follow:

```
public class MaintenanceTask
{
    private CancellationTokenSource m_CancellationTokenSource;
    private Task m_BatchTask;

    public MaintenanceTask()
    {            
        m_CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();            
    }

    public void AddTaskIdent(TaskIdentBase ident)
    {
        Task newTask = ident.Create(m_CancellationTokenSource.Token);

        if (m_BatchTask == null)
            m_BatchTask = newTask;            
        else                
            m_BatchTask.ContinueWith(prev=>newTask);                        
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        if (m_BatchTask != null)
            m_BatchTask.Start();
    }
}
```

The AddTaskIdent is recieving a base class that knows how to create the Task object.
My problem is that calling Run() start the first task that was sent to the class. It runs it until finished by no other task following it gets to run.
It's just stops after the first task is done.

Am I missing something with the ContinueWith mechanism ?

Comment: What is `TaskIdentBase`?

Comment: Just a class in my system that know what and how to create the different tasks. It's Create() returns the wanted Task object.

Comment: Yeah...the implementation is important...However I think you aren't using `Task` correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work after merging data from all answers and continuing googling.
The working class is:

```
public class MaintenanceTask
{
    private CancellationTokenSource m_CancellationTokenSource;
    private Task m_FirstTask;
    private Task m_LastTask;

    public MaintenanceTask()
    {
        m_CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void AddTaskIdent(TaskIdentBase ident)
    {
        Task newTask = ident.Create(m_CancellationTokenSource.Token);

        if (m_FirstTask == null)
        {
            m_FirstTask = newTask;
            m_LastTask = m_FirstTask;
        }
        else
        {                
            m_LastTask.ContinueWith(prev => newTask.Start());
            m_LastTask = newTask;
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        if (m_FirstTask != null)
            m_FirstTask.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that "foo.ContinueWith(completedTask => otherTask);" does not start otherTask. 
You need something like "foo.ContinueWith(completedTask => otherTask.Start());"

Try this in a debugger, that may help you see how this works:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task1 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("1"));
            Task task2 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("2"));
            Task task3 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("3"));

            task1.ContinueWith(previous => task2.Start());
            task2.ContinueWith(previous => task3.Start());

            task1.Start();
            task2.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
```

Comment: Tried it with only 2 tasks and still does not work. Also, changed the code to look like yours, not working.. my actionA/B/C are Task objects..

Comment: I think "my actions are Task objects" actually clarifies where the problem is. Hang on a minute....

Comment: I threw away the first half of the answer as it was wrong. The key thing is that ContinueWith takes an Action, not a Task. In your case you just need to make that Action START a Task. I'm actually not sure why the code in your question even compiles - it clearly does, of course, but it seems to me like it shouldn't. I'm about to learn something.... :-)

Comment: Tried it just now. Added the .Start() by then it does not have order.. all tasks just run together. I guess your test is working because the writeline() takes no time :\

Comment: In the second example (which I just deleted to avoid confusion) I was just illustrating that ContinueWith maintains a list, not a single next task. All continuations are invoked when the first task finishes, so if you want ordering you need to chain the tasks together as in the first (now only) example. Sorry for not being clearer about that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
m_BatchTask.ContinueWith(prev=>newTask);
```

I presume the `newTask` is not started when it's being returned from `ident.Create`.
So you should:

```
if (m_BatchTask != null)
{
    m_BatchTask = newTask;
    //you'd like to have the m_lastTask field because next chaining operation
    //should be on the last task, not the one you are starting
    m_lastTask = newTask;
}
else
{
    m_lastTask.ContinueWith(
        prev =>
        {
            newTask.Start();
            //doesn't matter to return newTask because in that case
            //on second chaining already you will get Task<Task>
            return (object)null; 
        });
    m_lastTask = newTask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the else branch with

```
  else                
        m_BatchTask.ContinueWith(prev=>newTask);
```

is called?

As I see m_Batch task is initially null when he applies next task to it but does not raise the continue with

Comment: It is called. When I add the first task it's not null anymore. The second task goes to the else part

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think you are using `Task` incorrectly. In most cases `Task` represents work that is happening already.

This is how I would go about writing the code you "want" assuming C#5.

```
public void AddToQueue(Action action)
{
    if (m_BatchTask == null)
        m_BatchTask = Task.Run(action);            
    else                
        m_BatchTask = AddToQueue(m_BatchTask, action);                        
}

public async Task AddToQueue(Task existingTask, Action action)
{
    await existingTask;
    action();                       
}
```